# python Invalid syntax in wsgi while hosting django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.10

I am using `Django 4.2.2` and `python 3.10` and I am having syntax errors in `wsgy.py` while hosting the server on AWS.

this is what i get in error.log

```
[wsgi:error]   mod_wsgi (pid=2084): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/project/wshp/wshp/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error]   mod_wsgi (pid=2084): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/wshp/wshp/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error]   Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]     File "/var/www/project/wshp/wshp/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[wsgi:error]       from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error]     File "/var/www/project/wshp/Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[wsgi:error]       from django.utils.version import get_version
[wsgi:error]     File "/var/www/project/wshp/Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[wsgi:error]       from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
[wsgi:error]     File "/var/www/project/wshp/Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py", line 10, in <module>
[wsgi:error]       from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
[wsgi:error]     File "/var/www/project/wshp/Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 265
[wsgi:error]       if (_wrapped := self._wrapped) is empty:
[wsgi:error]                    ^
[wsgi:error]   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If run migrations, or `run server` there is no issue.

I can not see what I have to upgrade and dont understand why  this `get_wsgi_application` does not understand walrus operator.
Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The error indicates the python running the code is < version 3.8.

Comment: How do you came to know that ? I know that `:=` does not work in python < 3.8. but my virtual environment is created using python3.10.

Comment: activate virtual env and check python version, and as well check  in debug which virtualenv/version is your app running?

Comment: `print(sys.version)` and `print(sys.executable)` inside your program to check exactly what you are running under (as opposed to what you think you are running under — I have definitely been guilty of this myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Python running your Django application is older than Python 3.8
Upgrade your Python version to at least Python 3.8 or Python 3.10 after that the code should work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**wsgi_mod **must** exactly match the version of Python.** In my case CentOS 8 package managemet (dnf) failed to ensure the dependency for python 3.9. dnf showed wsgi_mod38 and wsgi_mod39. Adapting manually with dnf fixed it.